# After camel upgrade to 3.1.0 weblogic 12c getting error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default configuration hasn't been specified

Tags: spring, apache-camel, ehcache, weblogic12c, redisson

After camel upgrade to 3.1.0 weblogic 12c getting error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default configuration hasn't been specified

```
<Oct 14, 2020 10:07:10,690 AM IST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "JAX-RS/Jersey#1" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "finnone-integration".
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default configuration hasn't been specified!
    at org.redisson.jcache.JCacheManager.createCache(JCacheManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.cache.CacheControlFeature.createCache(CacheControlFeature.java:119)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.cache.CacheControlFeature.configure(CacheControlFeature.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:730)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:648)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Oct 14, 2020 10:07:18,068 AM IST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149231> <Unable to set the activation state to true for the application "finnone-integration_INTG".
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default configuration hasn't been specified!
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default configuration hasn't been specified!
    at org.redisson.jcache.JCacheManager.createCache(JCacheManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.cache.CacheControlFeature.createCache(CacheControlFeature.java:119)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.cache.CacheControlFeature.configure(CacheControlFeature.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:730)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:648)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Comment: camel 3.1 is not considered stable, I'd recommend to switch to 3.5 which is an LTS version

Comment: Check out https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/2141 Try to place the config file in root of classpath with name redisson-jcache.json or redisson-jcache.yaml